# Which is the categorical variable in this research sample?

Tags: statistics

I think in this research, the variable is the toy type, not the gender. am I right?

Is gender associated with certain favorite toy as a child? Collect data using the following options: Barbies, Legos, Turtles, Video games, or dress-up clothes.

Comment: That depends entirely on how you sort your data.

Answer (score 0):

Actually no. You are trying to categorize the gender based on their favorite toy type. So in my opinion, the gender is the categorical variable in this question.

Comment: Are you certain that we aren't trying to categorize favourite toy based on gender?

Comment: Let's say you have a boy: do you want to be able to give him barbie, legos, turtles, ...specifically? In my opinion, in this question no. Because you want to be able to see if it's a boy; which of the set of toy types could be suitable for him, no?

Comment: @Arthur so if I were to make a data set, my individuals would be the toy types and my variable is gender right?

Comment: @Steven31415 so if I were to make a data set, my individuals would be the toy types and my variable is gender right?

Comment: @harpey1111: yes, gender seems to me the categorical variable in this research